# Getting a cell container from WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list view on a component which is bound to an observable collection of type BreakdownViewRow.

Each cell contains a component which operating in EDIT and DISPLAY modes.

I need to find a way to get to programatially change the mode on the cell content, but trying to iterate over the items in the list view returns objects of type BreakdownViewRow.

Is there a way I can access the cell containing each component, rather than getting back items as they exist in my observable collection?

The code for my component (the ContainerSelected event is bound in the XAML, and fires correctly passing the EditableControlContainer object as the sender):

```
public partial class ArrearsBreakdownView : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<BreakdownViewRow> rows;

    public ObservableCollection<BreakdownViewRow> Rows {
        get { return rows; }
        set { rows = value; }
    }

    public BreakdownView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        rows = new ObservableCollection<BreakdownViewRow>();

        Populate();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public void Populate() {
        rows.Add(new BreakdownViewRow(2015, 1000.50M, "TE1 \t Test Code 1", "This is a test row"));
        rows.Add(new BreakdownViewRow(2014, 100M, "TE1 \t Test Code 1", "Another row"));
        rows.Add(new BreakdownViewRow(2013, 150M, "TE1 \t Test Code 1", "This is a test row"));
    }

    public void ContainerSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        EditableControlContainer ecc = (EditableControlContainer)sender;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in grdArrears.Items) {
            //Here, I get a BreakdownViewRow object, when what I need is the EditableControlContainer object,
            //or the cell container
        }
        int stop = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `ItemContainerGenerator`. It'll return the container of the row, but you can then use the `TreeViewHelper` to get the ContentPresenters of each cell, and then look for your control inside each `ContentPresenter`'s Template:

```
public void ContainerSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    EditableControlContainer ecc = (EditableControlContainer)sender;
    ItemContainerGenerator generator = grdArrears.ItemContainerGenerator;

    foreach (var item in grdArrears.Items) {
        var itemContainer = generator.ContainerFromItem(item);

        foreach (var presenter in GetChildrenOfType<ContentPresenter>(itemContainer))
        {
            var myControl = presenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("MyControl", presenter);
            // Do stuff with your cell control
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

        if (child is T)
            yield return (T)child;

        var childrenOfType = GetChildrenOfType<T>(child);

        foreach (var childOfType in childrenOfType)
            yield return childOfType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The item which is returned is a ListViewItem which contains a BreakdownViewRow.

Comment: I see, you want to get cells instead of rows, right? In that case, it's not that easy... You'll have to resort to searching through the visual tree. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's it, I need to get the cell so I can change the mode on all the EditableControlContainer objects to Display, apart from the one which has been selected. Thank you!

Comment: Edited. Keep in mind that here I'm using the `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` function, which is the easier way to do this if you can set a Name to the control you wanna fetch... If for whatever reason you can't set the Name, let me know.

Comment: That looks like it could be spot on! I'm out at the moment but shall try this when I get back in. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! As I want to get all the cells for each of the 4 columns, I've had to encapsulate each in a check for null to get all the columns after the foreach. This seems like such a faff compared to winforms!

Comment: Well, yeah, WPF is a lot less straightforward than WinForms for some stuff :P But you know what they say... With great flexibility and power comes a great deal of extra problems!